# Importing redux actions from other files to compose redux-thunks (using Ducks)

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I've been structuring my redux bundles using the [Ducks pattern](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) and so far it's working really well. However, one use case that I haven't quite figured out is how I'm supposed to write thunks that dispatch actions from multiple different files.

For example, I have one redux bundle file that looks like

```
// redux/geo.js

const NAME = 'myapp/geo'
const POSITION_CHANGE = `${NAME}/POSITION_CHANGE`

const initialState = {
  position: {},
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POSITION_CHANGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        position: action.value
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function getPositionAsync() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => resolve(position),
      (error) => reject(error),
    )
  })
}

export function positionChange(value) {
  return {type: POSITION_CHANGE, value}
}
```

and another

```
// redux/search.js

import {getPositionAsync, positionChange} from './geo.js' // doesn't seem to work... do I need to import something else?

const NAME = 'myapp/search'
const RESULTS_SHOW = `${NAME}/RESULTS_SHOW`

const initialState = {
  showResults: false,
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RESULTS_SHOW:
      return {
        ...state,
        showResults: action.value,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function resultsShow(value) {
  return {type: RESULTS_SHOW, value}
}

// thunk that is composed of actions from geo.js and search.js
export function executeSearch() {
  return dispatch => getPositionAsync()
    .then(position => dispatch(positionChange(position)))
    .then(() => dispatch(resultsShow(true)))
}
```

but this gives me an error when I attempt to dispatch the `executeSearch` thunk. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always return promise, in your case the problem is dispatch do not return promise, try the code below

```
export function executeSearch() {
  return dispatch => getPositionAsync()
     .then(position => {
          dispatch(positionChange(position));
          dispatch(resultsShow(true))
     })
 }
```